# How to "Investigate rock arches on the Mun" in Kerbal Space Program?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm doing historical missions, the "Investigate rock arches on the Mun" mission.

I've reached the Arch, taken samples, EVA, Crew reported, landed really near it (<100m), climbed it's top + crew report + Samples.. and still the contract is not satisfied.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I think it's a bug. I've been there a second time, still nothing happens.

Screenshot added:
[image]

Comment: When you are in proximity to the arches, does your kerbal have another option, in the right-click menu? (Ie besides plant flag, gather surface sample, etc.?)

Comment: Not that I know of, I'll recheck again.

Comment: It's just a couple of thoughts, but maybe you need to activate the EVA jet pack near the arch. (That'd be daft, but still.) Maybe try different Kerbal types?

Comment: @Grimm - Interesting idea, using different kerbals, unfortunately it's been so long that I can't test it ;-), but still - thanks for the idea, hopefully someone will use it.

Comment: Thanks all for your time.

For others, in short: this might be the cause of: 
1. a bug (that was/will be fixed).
2. a plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

Have you visited **all** the arches on the Mun? The easter egg KSP wiki page says:

> Three giant rock arches can be found at 12° 27′ 2″ N 39° 11′ 45″ E, 12° 28′ 18″ S 140° 57′ 40″ W, and 2° 27′ 47″ N 81° 31′ 51″ E.

You have only explored **one** arch. If you find the others and explore them, you should complete the contract.

Comment: TY Enrico, still playing KSP, and I do hope this answer will help others.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have to return the sample back to Kerbin?

Otherwise, I would check the contract again in the Mission Control building at KSC. The description of the contract there might be more specific than the UI tooltip.

Comment: No, this isn't the case. If the objective is to "Visit",  you should receive credit as soon as you "visit". The only time you need to return to Kerbin is for missions that explicitly state that something needs to be returned. (People, samples, or just the vessel in general.)

Comment: Thanks Whether-Man for your reply, but 'Tim S' is right.
Since it was a year ago from current date, I can't remember if I installed plug-ins, but this might be the case.

In short: this might be the cause of: 
1. a bug (that was/will be fixed).
2. a plug-in.